# CUDA-GDB: Setting Up the Debugger Environment

Tags: cuda, cuda-gdb

I'm following the [CUDA-GDB guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/cuda-gdb.pdf) (page 10, getting started) on Ubuntu Linux and got this:

```
antonio@antonio-desktop:~$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
antonio@antonio-desktop:~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/
antonio@antonio-desktop:~$ lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
bash: lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/: No such file or directory
```

Well, how do I fix this? I have the current toolkit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have broken a line in two - it should be:

```
$ export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You probably got confused by the line wrap in the nVidia PDF.